# Monitor keeps waking up when on sleep

Tags: 22.04

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 with the default power saving setting to blank screen after five minutes. When my display goes to sleep, it immediately turns on again, stays black and after a few seconds shows no signal and turns off again, just to be waken up in less then ten seconds. Then the cycle repeats nonstop. Any ideas how to stop this behavior?

Comment: I have the same issue. For me, I have a dual monitor setup, AMD Radeon, both monitors are Samsung 4K connected via DisplayPort. If I manually power off one monitor, the sleep works with the remaining monitor. It seems like the event of the second monitor going to sleep is triggering the OS to wake them back up. Have you been able to solve this?